# Declare variable without var outside 'use strict'

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why it throws error

```js
str = 'string'; // str is not defined. Why?
let str = 'string2';

console.log(str);
```

I thought declaring a variable without a keyword would make it look like a var. But it is not.

Comment: How does the JS interpreter behave when a variable Declaration occurs without a keyword? Why do I get this error?

Comment: The actual error I see (in FireFox) is "*`ReferenceError`: can't access lexical declaration `str` before initialization*" This should indicate the actual problem is the `let` within the same block, and indeed if you remove the `let str =` it works fine.

Comment: Put that `let` on the first line instead of the second line, or just simply get rid of it.

Comment: you cannot access 'str' before initialization

Comment: You should first declare the variable `var str;`

Comment: @goodvibration I know what this working. Bit I don't understand why I get error

Comment: javascript doesn't allow implicit variable declarations

Comment: You're confusing the interpreter, that why it's not working.

Comment: @Plastic it absolutely does. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description): "*Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed.*" Modern coding standards recommend using strict mode which forbids this, but this is something you need to opt in to.

Comment: @p.s.w.g you are absolutely right. it's just forbidden in strict mode

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variable first, then use it, that's how `let` works. If you were using the `var` keyword instead it would have worked.

Using `let`

```
str = 'string';        // DOES NOT WORK! here it hasn't been declared
let str = 'string2';   // move this line up before the above line

console.log(str);
```

Using `var`

```
str = 'string';        // IT WORKS because of variable hoisting!
var str = 'string2';

console.log(str);
```

See: [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)